# SELECT rows having same value in two fields, and different value in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows that have the same value in `column1` and `column2` but differ in `column3`.

Here's my table.

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | J | abc |
| a | K | def |
| a | L | xyz |
| b | J | abc |
| b | J | def |
| b | L | xyz |
| c | K | def |
| c | K | def |

Here's the output I want.

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| b | J |

Here's what I tried.

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM my_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
HAVING COUNT(column1) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to select rows that have the same value in column1 and column2 but differ in column3.

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where exists (select 1
              from my_table t2
              where t2.column1 = t.column1 and t2.column2 = t.column2 and
                    t2.column3 <> t.column3
             );
```

Your sample results, though, suggest that you just want `column1`/`column2` pairs.  If so:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM my_table
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING MIN(column3) <> MAX(column3);
```

Your version of the query just returns `column1`/`column2` pairs that have a `column3` value with more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it, small correction over your version:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2
FROM my_table
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column3) > 1;
```